# My stopwords is not doing anything. what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, nltk

```
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
corpus_root = 'fradulentemail'
newcorpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root,'.*')
sentence = newcorpus.sents()[:50]
all_words = [[word.lower() for word in text] for text in sentence]
for stopword in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'):
    if stopword in all_words:
        del all_words[stopword]
```

Also, doing newcorpus.raw() gives me error gives me error as "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 118396: invalid start byte". please help

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at `all_words = [[word.lower() for word in text] for text in sentence]`, you'll realise that `all_words` is a list of list. Change the code to something like the following, and it should work:

```
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

corpus_root = 'fradulentemail'
newcorpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root,'.*')
sentences = newcorpus.sents()[:50]

all_non_stop_words = [[word.lower() for word in text if word.lower() not in stop_words] for text in sentences]
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
del all_words[stopword]
```

You have use the index of stopword in all_word not stopword itself
Try this

```
stopwords=nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
all_words=[ word for word in all_words if word not in stopwords]
print(all_words)
```